# How to dynamically update the synonym filter data base

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to dynamically update my synonym filter data base in Elasticsearch. As Im doing a synonym training process with my app, is it possible to add new words to the synonym words data base dynamically in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my-index/_close'
echo
echo updating new Synynom database
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my-index/_settings' -d @analyzer.json
echo
echo Opening index
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my-index/_open'
```

analyzer.json file looks like below -

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "his-synonym": {
        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "my-synonym"
        ]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "my-synonym": {
        "type": "synonym",
        "synonyms": [
          "big,large",
          "run,jogg"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your synonyms are kept in a file, then you need to update the file, close the index and then re-open it and it should pick up the new synonyms automatically.